# Trigonometric expression in greatest integer function.

Tags: trigonometry

If $$f(x)=\left[\cos x\cdot \cos(x+2)- \cos^2(x+1) \right]$$ where [.] denotes the greatest integer function $\le x$. Then what would be the  number of solutions of the equation $$f(x)=x$$

I tried to manipulate the expression of $\cos x \cdot \cos (x+2)$ by using the product-sum formula and then changed the $\cos 2(x+1)$ expression into $2\cos^2(x+1)-1$ but came to know that we can't manipulate the expression in such a way (multiplying and dividing by $2$ to use product-sum formulae) as the whole function is that of the greatest integer one.

Can anybody just give me a hint on how I can start with the question?

Comment: Is the answer 1?

Comment: @ShreyAryan The number of solutions is 1 and the solution  is (-1).

Comment: Were you able to solve it using mathlove's hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculation gives that the function $$y=\cos x\cdot \cos(x+2)- \cos^2(x+1)$$ is identically equal to $-\sin^2 1$ so $$[y]=x\iff x=-1$$ In fact
$$y=\cos^2x\cos 2-\sin x\cos x\sin 2-(\cos^2 x\cos^2 1+\sin^2 x\sin^2 1-2\sin x\cos x\sin 1\cos 1)$$
Making now $\sin 2=2\sin 1\cos 1$, $\cos 2= \cos^2 1-\sin^2 1$ and simplifying you have the result.

Answer (score 1):

HINT : I think you can get the answer in your method.

Using that
$$\cos(A)\cos(B)=\frac 12(\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B))$$
gives that
$$\cos(x)\cos(x+2)=\frac 12(\cos(2(x+1))+\cos(2))$$

Now use that $\cos(2C)=2\cos^2(C)-1$ with $-1\lt\cos(2)\lt 0$.